# Adding a Condition in Django Template Not Working

Tags: django

I have a model called Posts where users may have posts and may not have any posts, what I am trying to do is in the template to have condition that if the user has posts to have a button appearing to link to this page of posts otherwise to show nothing.

There is no error showing it is simply not working as I want

here is the posts model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    designer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

here is the template

```
<a href="{% url 'core:designer-posts' item.designer.username %}">
<button style="margin-top: 10px;text-transform: none;" button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block">
Check all my products </button>
</a>
{% if post.designer.id is not None %}
<a href="{% url 'score:user-posts' item.designer.username %}">
<button style="margin-top: 10px;text-transform: none;" button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block">
Check my posts </button>
</a>
{% else %}
Show Nothing
{% endif %}
```

The template also has another model which is the item which is also the same user
Here is the model

```
class Item(models.Model):
    designer = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Here is the views

```
class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Item
    paginate_by = 12
    template_name = "home.html"
    ordering = ['-timestamp']

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context['posts'] = Post
    return context
```

Answer (score 0):

you are passing the key "posts" in the context and your if is against "post", try this correction:

```py
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ClassView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['post'] = Post
    return context
```

Comment: Yes, its a typo but it is not the reason for the bug, the buttons are showing although some users have no posts. What i want is that the button doesn't appear when there are no posts related to the user.

Answer (score 0):

In your `get_context_data` method, you're just passing the reference of a class `Post` which is not useful for extracting the information if the user has any posts or not.

**try this:**

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context["posts"] = Post.objects.filter(
        designer=some_designer
    ).exist()  # This will return a boolean value
```

and inside your template, use this condition to enable button link

```
{% if posts %}
```

Comment: I got `TypeError at /
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'ForwardManyToOneDescriptor'` error after replacing some_designer with `Item.designer`

Comment: may I ask what is the type of `self.request.user`? Is it `User`.

Comment: Where is `self.request.user` ?

Comment: you can use the debugger to check `self.request.user` in `get_context_data` method. Basically what I am asking is which Database or Model class is associated with a logged-in user.